# How to least privilege Microsoft Graph API daemon application permissions to a single OneDrive Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

Trying to leverage the Microsoft Graph API within a daemon application to update a single OneDrive Excel file. How do I accomplish least privilege permissions to a single file. I have scoured the documentation for a straightforward explanation of this basic task, however no articles are instructive on how to proceed with this. The documentation appears to define least privilege as a distinction between the Office software entities, but not within folders and files of a OneDrive. Thanks in advance for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The `Files.{Read|ReadWrite}.All` application scopes provide access to the entire Drive for every user.

From the Permissions [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#application-permissions-19):

> - `Files.Read.All`: Allows the app to read *all files in all site collections* without a signed in user.
> - `Files.ReadWrite.All`:  Allows the app to read *all files in all site collections* without a signed in user.